# The "And of 3" in Robert Cray's song "Will You Think Of Me"

Tags: rhythm

What do you call the rhythm being employed in Robert Cray's song "Will You Think Of Me" -- where the drummer is emphasizing the upbeat or "and" of the third beat in the measure?

Can be heard starting at 25 seconds into this video:

Answer (score 2):

Off-beat Syncopation. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncopation) has a brief discussion on Syncopation. Notice that he doesn't do it on every measure, making it an effective use of the technique.